# hidden field changes value when saving form django

Tags: python, django

This is my model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    is_ignore_validations = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and this is my form

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name',
                  'is_ignore_validations',
                  ]
        is_ignore_validations = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
```

The usage for `is_ignore_validations` is in the `clean_name()` function

```
def clean_name():
    original_name = self.data.get('name')
    if not self.initial.get('is_ignore_validations'):
        pattern = re.compile('^[a-zA-Z]+$')
        if not pattern.match(original_name):
            raise ValidationError('name must consist only of letters')

    return original_name
```

I initiate my form with `request.POST`, which doesn't have `is_ignore_validations`.
I want it to stay how I've set it manually in the DB, but when I use `form.save()` it always changes to `False`.

So firstly, how do I keep `is_ignore_validations` data in DB always the same?

Secondly, is the usage in `clean_name` of the variable from initial best practice - `self.initial.get('is_ignore_validations')`?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to have is_ignore_validations in your form.

Comment: it is necessary. if not for the field in the form I wouldn't be able to do `self.initial.get('is_ignore_validations')`

Comment: As I understood you don't want to update is_ignore_validations. You just one to check the current person is_ignore_validations. If it's true you can have another form for update and pass person id to POST; e.g: api.com/updateuser/{id} and in post query person and get is_ignore_validations.

Comment: Can you please share your view where you initiate the form?